# Generate a custom number sequence using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following array :

```
var sequence = new double?[] {null, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
                             18, 19, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30,32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 44,48, 52, 
                             56, 60, 64, 68,72, 76, 80, 88, 96, 104, 112, 120, 128, 136, 144
                              };
```

I would like to obtain the same sequence but to generate it using linq

Comment: Do you have a formula for determining the numbers?

Comment: @mjwills ... it just for informational purpose, was curios about the linq syntax.

Comment: @RufusL ... after 20 increment by 2 .. after 40 increment by 4 ... after 80 increment by 8 ... till 144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two possible versions for generating the number part of the array:

A `Concat` version for each of the ranges

```
var r = Enumerable.Range(3, 17)
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => 20 + i * 2))
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => 40 + i * 4))
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select(i => 80 + i * 8))
    .ToArray();
```

A version using `SelectMany` and value tuples:

```
var r2 = new[] { (3, 17), (0, 10), (0, 10), (0, 9) }
    .SelectMany((_, i) => Enumerable.Range(_.Item1, _.Item2).Select(n => 20 * (1 << (i - 1)) + n * (1 << i)))
    .ToArray();
```

Weather either version is more readable than the original is up for debate :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another version:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Numbers()
{
    int[] inc = {1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8};

    for (int n = 3; n <= 144; n += inc[n / 20])
        yield return n;
}
```

Or if you want to be a bit obtuse:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Numbers()
{
    for (int n = 3; n <= 144; n += "12448888"[n/20]-'0')
        yield return n;
}
```

(That second suggestion is a joke - don't do that, it's unreadable!)

[EDIT] Here's a third approach, slightly saner:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Numbers()
{
    for (int n = 3; n <= 144; n += 1 + (n>=20?1:0) + (n>=40?2:0) + (n>=80?4:0))
        yield return n;
}
```

Comment: The second version [rocks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

> after 20 increment by 2 .. after 40 increment by 4 ... after 80 increment by 8 ... till 144

Don't use linq in such cases, unless you want on purpose to increase the difficulty of understanding your code. A simple loop:

```
static IEnumerable<double?> Data()
{
    yield return null;
    for (int value = 3; value <= 144; value++) // increment by 1 by default
    {
        yield return value;
        if (value >= 20) value += 1;
        if (value >= 40) value += 2;
        if (value >= 80) value += 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most readable answer; I'd use this one personally. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This my be worth considering:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(3, 17)
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(10, 10).Select(z => z * 2))
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(10, 11).Select(z => z * 4))
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(11, 8).Select(z => z * 8));
var resultWithNull = new double?[] {null}.Concat(result.Select(z => (double?)z)).ToArray();
```

*The second `var` is to concatenate `null` at the start.*

To be clear, I think your original code is better...